# Difficulty vertically centering contents of bootstrap 4 column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

The problem I am having is if I apply my-auto class to my column div, everything vertically centers as expected, but so does the div's background image. I have tried wrapping only the contents in a div and applying my-auto, applying vertically centering css classes to the column div that only target the children or first child of the element (Usually results in a loss of responsiveness). I'm not entirely sure what to try next and it's getting a bit frustrating. Everything I try either smashes the top and bottom of the image into the center of the column with it's contents. Or causes the contents to no longer be responsive and come out of the column when the screen size gets smaller.

my HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-6 mail-bg text-black">
                <h1>Subscribe to our Mailing List!</h1>
                <p>Sign up and stay up to date with anything Any Given Room! By
                    signing up you will receive a 10% discount on our merch for life!
                    And if you get tired of us? Cancel your subscription at any time.
                <p>
                    <span class="text-danger"
                        ng-show="subForm.subInput.$touched && subForm.subInput.$invalid"><b>Email
                            field cannot be empty.</b></span>
                <form name="subForm">
                    <div class="form-group my-3">
                        <input type="text" name="subInput" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="mailForm.email" required>
                    </div>
                    <a class="w3-button w3-black w3-border my-3" type="submit"
                        ng-click="subscribe()">Subscribe</a>
                </form>
        </div>
```

My css class that adds a background image. (Just for clarity)

```
.mail-bg {
    background-image: url("./images/letter background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What are you try to center? can you clarify better?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Pretty much everything in the outer div.  From the opening tag of the h1 to the closing tag of the form.